# Why do we transform proportions and what are the methods to do that?

Tags: data-transformation, proportion

When proportions are condensed below 1%. It become asymmetric on the distribution curve, so we get the log() of the proportions to make it symmetric around zero. Is that correct what else can the transformation be used for? Is there methods to transform proportions other than log?

Comment: With proportions, several transformed scales can make sense, especially logit. You need to do something different if the proportion is actually zero. Your comment "symmetric around zero" makes no obvious sense, as symmetry around zero for proportions would imply half the proportions being negative and symmetry around zero for log proportions would imply half of the proportions being above 1.

Comment: you can also use a [logit transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit) i.e. $log(p/(1-p))$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking logs of proportions/probabilities really makes sense when computing likelihoods. Why? Because for independent observations, the probability of getting all those observations is given by multiplying them. But that quickly leads to very small numbers and underflow. So it makes sense to sum log(p) instead to get the log likelihood.
Note that you need to beware of log(0) when doing logs on probabilities.